# update-initramfs: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, kernel, initramfs, tools

I'm using Kubuntu 13.04 x64. I found out about this problem after installing Nvidia drivers from jockey and seeing that nouveau was still loading instead.

I tried to manually reinstall nvidia-current but initramfs-update fails:

```
$ update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-23-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-23-generic with 1.
```

This errors started after trying to install Nvidia drivers, but it most probably is unrelated.  As I understand from fixrtc, it's just trying to set the correct time using time, dumpe2fs and hwclock.

Can you tell me what's happening? I can't build initrd images with initramfs-tools failing on the fixrtc hook.

Comment: Worked around it by removing the executable flag from fixrtc with `sudo chmod -x /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc`. Now update-initramfs completes building an initrd image. Is there anything bad that could happen by removing fixrtc as I did? I'm still curious about what happened!

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by Montblanc,

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc
```

will solve the issue.

Comment: I did this once, run what was failing to finish again. It got past the failing point, but didn't finish all successfully. The I ran chmod +x /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc again, and now all is good.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be magically resolved in 3.8.0-24

Comment: Stumbled back upon it while upgrading to 13.10. Had to toggle again the executive flag.